# How to remove vertical scroll in kendo chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-chart, gridstack

I am loading kendo chart inside grid-stack.js, unable to resize height. I am getting scroll if I decrease the height . I should not get vertical scroll if I resize.

I have tried giving height:auto and tried refreshing chart after resizing

```
$('body').delegate(".grid-stack-item", "resizestop", function (event, ui) {
    $('.' + $(this).find('.panel')
                   .attr('data-chart-id'))
                   .data("kendoChart")
                   .refresh();
    $("." + $(this).find('.panel')
                   .attr('data-chart-id')) 
                   .css({ 'height': ($(this)
                   .height() - 40) + 'px !important' })
                   .data("kendoChart")
                   .resize(); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Yes if I give overflow:hidden also it is not working

Comment: By not working do you mean the chart doesn't work or that the scroll is still visible? In case of the latter, `overflow: hidden;` works 100% of the time, so you might have to find out which container is actually receiving the scrollbar. Posting your HTML code would make it easier to find the solution.

Comment: scroll is still visible. I am trying to hide vertical scroll

Comment: In that case find out which element has the scroll bar with the inspector and give the property to that. If you can't find it, post your HTML and I'll check it.

Comment: `<div class="panel-body">
<div class=" charts charts0 k-chart" data-chart-type="pie" data-role="chart" style="position: relative;overflow:hidden;"><svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; left: -0.15625px; top: 0px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"><defs><radialGradient id="kdef32" cx="357" cy="200" r="133" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<text style="font:12px sans-serif;white-space:pre;" x="340.472" y="78.038" stroke="none" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="1">0.8%</text></g></g></svg>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: Above is the code but still I am getting vertical scroll for that

Comment: I am adding kendo-chart inside gridstack.js